# Angular webpack ui-bootstrap not pulling in css

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

So I'm making an Angular application using Webpack, and I wanted to bring in bootstrap for styling.

I installed 'ui-bootstrap' using `npm install angular-ui-bootstrap --save-dev`, and then I imported it in `app.js`, and passed it as a dependency to the `angular.module('myapp', [dependencies....])`. That worked, and I was getting the javascript functionality for bootstrap elements. e.g. toggle button was working fine.

However, there was no styling. The button was styled as a regular html button.

So, I tried doing the same thing for `bootstrap` with npm. That gave me an error saying jquery not defined (I was using vanilla js), so I tried getting Jquery with npm, and that still gave me an error saying Jquery is not defined.

What's the correct process for getting angular-ui-bootrap functionality and styling while using webpack?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

import only the css module from bootstrap

No need to inject any bootstrap elements in the angular module, since bootstrap does not have any angular components. Do, however, inject angular-ui-bootstrap.

Comment: Sorry what is the line of code you used to add bootstrap css?  I'm trying import 'angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-csp.css'; but its not working.

Comment: I used this: `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';`

Comment: You're importing the bootstrap css from the ui-bootstrap, not bootstrap itself.  You should do `npm install bootstrap --save-dev` first, then import the css from bootstrap. Bootstrap css is a required dependency for angular ui bootstrap.

Comment: I'm getting jQuery is not defined error.  Guess i need to include that too?

Comment: I had that error at first, when I was importing bootstrap entirely. That error disappeared after I just imported the css.`import 'angular-ui-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` and I just had `angular.module('psa', ['ui.router', 'angularModalService', 'ngFileUpload', 'ui.bootstrap'])`. You should not need jQuery, as that is not a required dependency for ui-bootstrap, as said in the docs. If it says you need jquery, you may be accidentally importing parts of bootstrap that require jquery

Comment: Glad it worked out. Took me a long time to figure out 3 lines of code :P